# How to not call a function of outer section on click of inner section of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

[Plaese have a look on Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNqmO.png)

I have 2 nested HTML Section, where in first section i am calling a function (lets suppose it is ABC();) and in Second section calling function (suppose it is XYZ();) using onClick(). 
Second section is inside of first section as show in fig.

On click of section-2, function XYZ(); gets call and function ABC() as well as it lies in its parent section.

My requirement to call only function XYZ() on click of section-2 but not ABC() which is its parents section's function.

for example -

```
<div onClick='ABC();'>
    Some more code...
    <span onClick='XYZ()'>Click here</span>
</div>
```

on click of `<span>` tag section only XYZ() function should get call not ABC() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prevent click event from bubbling up the DOM tree with `$event.stopPropagation` method:

```
<div ng-click='ABC();'>
    Some more code...
    <span ng-click='XYZ(); $event.stopPropagation();'>Click here</span>
</div>
```